# File rename issue

Tags: linux, shell

Need your kind assistance in fixing the file rename issue in the following shell script.

Issue description: `$name` will get more than one file name and all file names will be stored as a combined string with space.

When I rename my prefix is getting appended to the entire string.

But I need that prefix to be appended for each file name separately.

```
cd /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP
test=`find . -type f -name "*.csv" -mmin +5 | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
cp $test /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMPARCHIVENEW/
mv $test /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP_SFTP/
cd /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP_SFTP/
name=`find . -type f -name "*.csv"| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
for i in $name
do
    newname="Yes!28887:""$(echo "$test")"
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
mv $newname /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP2/
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.csv"| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
```

instead of assigning to a variable

Comment: or better, `basename`